# Operatornorm of powers of Matricies with integer coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, general-linear-group

Let $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ have infinite order, so $A^k\neq Id_n$ for all $k>0$. The operator norm is defined by $\lVert A \rVert=\max\{\lVert Av\rVert \mid v\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lVert v\rVert=1\}$. It´s easy to see, that $\lVert A\rVert > 1$.
My question is:

Is $\lVert A^k \rVert\geq k$ for all (big enough) $k$? If not, is there a constant $C>0$ with $\lVert A^k \rVert\geq Ck$ for all (big enough) $k$?

It feels like there should be some easy solution, since there are only finitely many matrices with integer coefficients with operator norm at most $k$ (or $Ck$), and since $A$ has infinite order, I should eventually outgrow them, but I have no nice formal argument.

Answer (score 4):

There are two cases:

1. $\rho(A)>1$. Then $\|A^k\|_2\ge\rho(A^k)=\rho(A)^k$.
2. $\rho(A)\le1$. Then $1=|\det(A)|=\prod_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|\le1$, where the $\lambda_k$s denote the eigenvalues of $A$ over $\mathbb C$. Therefore $|\lambda_i|=1$ for every $i$. In turn, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients and unimodular roots. It follows from a [result](https://mathoverflow.net/q/10911) by Kronecker that all $\lambda_i$s are roots of unity. Hence $A$ is not diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$, or else $A$ will have a finite order. Therefore, some eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$ is not semi-simple, i.e., the Jordan form $J$ of $A$ contains a principal submatrix $\pmatrix{\lambda_i&1\\ 0&\lambda_i}$. It follows that
   $$
   \|J^k\|_F
   \ge\left\|\pmatrix{\lambda_i&1\\ 0&\lambda_i}^k\right\|_F
   =\left\|\pmatrix{\lambda_i^k&k\lambda_i\\ 0&\lambda_i^k}\right\|_F
   >k.
   $$

It follows from the two cases above that there exists come $C>0$ such that $\|A^k\|_2\ge Ck$ for every integer $k\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. One follow up question: in case 1: is there a lower limit on $\rho (A)$, say $\rho (A)\geq r>1$, which is independent from the matrix $A$? So basically, can I choose the constant $C$ independently from the Matrix $A$?

Comment: @delta I don’t know. From the discussions in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/114745), I have the (probably wrong) impression that this is an open problem.

Comment: @delta To add a bit of specificity, if one assumes that Wikipedia is up to date, then the truth of the as yet unproven conjecture about Salem numbers (and known results regarding Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers) would imply that we have the universal lower bound $r \approx 1.17628$, which is the largest real solution of $x^{10} + x^9 -x^7 -x^6 -x^5 -x^4 -x^3 +x +1 = 0$.

Comment: @delta This bound can be made smaller for small values of $n$. For example, if we consider only the case where $n = 2$, the best lower bound is the golden ratio, $r = \phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.61803$.